# Hide Accounts to Partner Users

Tags: partner-communities, sharing-rule

Our OWD Setting is:

**Account, Contract and Asset** - Public Read Only

**Opportunity** - Private

We have a sharing rule that enables Partner Users to view and edit internal opportunities. However, this gives them the ability to also **view** the account record associated in the opportunity.

Is there a way to totally hide the Accounts to our Partner users (Partner Community license) ?

Even though it's just view access we still don't want them to view any Accounts.

Comment: Why not change the OWD for external to private ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to hide them, but as a last resort you could create a Layout specific to their profile that has most fields removed.  This way while they may have access, they won't see much of anything.